# PHP fgetcsv encounters Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded on Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, fatal-error, execution-time, fgetcsv

First of all I guess that "fatal error: maximum execution time exceeded" in PHP is a server side error and shouldn't depend on browser version, right? But seems it does!?!

I have this code to read csv data coming from a text area in a form.

```
$handle = tmpfile();
fwrite($handle, $csvclip);
fseek($handle, 0);
while (!feof($handle)) {
   $r = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter, '"'); <---- Here it gives Fatal Error
   print $r[0];
}
```

And data is this, nothing special, 4 columns and 3 rows.

```
a   b   1   2
c   d   3   4
e   f   5   6
```

Code works on all browsers (IE, Chrome, e.t.c), I can see my parsed data except Firefox!!!!! I tested on different PCs but same. All browsers are ok but Firefox gives "Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded" for line having "fgetcsv"

I'm using PHP Version 5.2.10 and 2 different firefox versions 3.5.16 and 3.6.6

Anyone have seen this problem before?

Edit: Code is tested on two different linux servers CentOS 5.3 and 5.5, using two different PC having all browsers.

**Edit 2: SOLVED**

Ok I found the problem. $delimiter value comes from a  having 3 values "," ";" and "\t" which browsers display "\t" as spaces in  and I didn't pay attention to it.

Seems firefox is doing something to \t so PHP doesn't understand that it's tab. But other browsers sends \t as expected.

If I hardcode "\t" like fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", '"') works fine also with firefox.

First time Firefox caused me that much trouble and not IE :)

Comment: Why are you reading form data from a tempfile?

Comment: How large is the data you input?

Comment: What is your `max_execution_time` (in php.ini) currently set to? Could try increasing that as a short term fix in order to allow you to carry on development while trying to figure the problem out.

Comment: @Zimbabao
I write string data coming from a TEXTAREA to a tmp file so fgetcsv can read it using file pointer.

@Pekka
Data is in the question, only 4 lines

@Luke Max Execution Time is 30 seconds which should be enough for 4 lines of data

Comment: there is no problem with time execution wtf its up to the server not browser :), u may have to split the data of ur svc. as it may be too large for firefox that the only explaination and show data in chunks

Comment: :) like I said, data is only 4 lines :), another thing I noticed, until firefox gives this error, Server CPU usage goes 100% !?! then it drops after fatal error

Comment: What's in the rest of your loop? You could have something there that's taking a long time to run

Comment: @Mark Baker
I edited my code, please check. That's the actual loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. $delimiter value comes from a having 3 values "," ";" and "\t" which browsers display "\t" as spaces in and I didn't pay attention to it.

Seems firefox is doing something to \t so PHP doesn't understand that it's tab. But other browsers sends \t as expected.

If I hardcode "\t" like fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", '"') works fine also with firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the top of your script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This should disable the time limit for your script to run.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the problem here, but take a look at Tom's comments from 24-Oct-2006 10:27 on the [feof() page](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php)